# MySQL8 instance crashes on CloudSQL

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql

i had a MySQL 5.7 instance on Google CloudSQL.
Now i created a MySQL 8 instance.

The configuration is pretty much the same (except i use 2 CPUs instead of one, 3.75GB of RAM).
Now the default config for MySQL Memory usage (like innodb_buffer_pool_size,..) seems to be the same.

I migrated about half of my applications to use this instance. What is happening now is, that the instance Memory usage goes above 3.XX GB and the service gets restarted.
Which is super annoying because in that time my applications obviously crash.
It seems like memory usage grows with every select statement, and everything is cached.

Here are some of the config values:

```
|                          key_buffer_size |           8.00 MB |
|                  innodb_buffer_pool_size |        1408.00 MB |
|                   innodb_log_buffer_size |          16.00 MB |
|                         sort_buffer_size |           0.25 MB |
|                         read_buffer_size |           0.125 MB |
|                     read_rnd_buffer_size |           0.25 MB |
|                         join_buffer_size |           0.25 MB |
|                             thread_stack |           0.273 MB |
|                        binlog_cache_size |           0.031 MB |
|                           tmp_table_size |          16.00 MB |
```

This makes CloudSQL pretty much unusable to me. I need MySQL 8 without crashing several times a day.

Comment: Do you realize 1408,000 MB is 1.4 *terabytes* of RAM? I'm guessing that's more than your 2CPU instance has. Even the log buffer is 16 GB.

Comment: Show the actual config values and not "displayed" config values due to country usage of commas/periods in numbers.

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake. Those values would be innodb_buffer_pool_size: 1476395008 and innodb_log_buffer_size: 16777216

Comment: Please check the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on what topics you can ask on StackOverflow. This question involves database troubleshooting so it's best asked on DBA StackExchange. You're more likely to get answers from there.

Comment: Thank you! i posted it on DBA StackExchange.